# Embebed an iframe in Sharepoint from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, iframe

I'd like to know if it's possible to embebed an Iframe on Sharepoint that will populate some personal information retrieved from a Data Extension.
If the user was to update those values, the Data Extension would be updated. 
Is this something doable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CloudPage and set that as a `src` attribute value in your iframe element.

Regarding your requirement to 'populate some personal information retrieved from a Data Extension', I assume you want to pre-populate the child page with fields from a Data Extension. Is that correct? If so then you will need to append URL parameter(s) to the CloudPage URL. Assuming that you can do this in Sharepoint, then I can't see any reason why this would not work.

And yes, you can update a Data Extension record with values from form fields on your page using the [UpdateDE()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/updatede/) AMPscript function.

Comment: Thanks Elliot for your answer! What if instead of using an Iframe (which is not an option apparently), we used an interface? Is this an option?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Sharepoint, so I can't answer that question, sorry.